# bin_at(): failed to cast argument 3 to scalar constant

Tags: kql

Why does this query work :

```
let traces = traces| take 10 | extend LSA_optimization_sliding_win = "0";
traces
|  summarize AggregatedValue = dcount(roleInstanceId) by bin_at(timestamp, 30m, (datetime(2021-04-05T23:27:46.0000000)  - 15m * (2 - toint(LSA_optimization_sliding_win))))
```

while this one produces error : **bin_at(): failed to cast argument 3 to scalar constant**

```
 let traces = traces| take 10 | mv-expand LSA_optimization_sliding_win = range(0, 2, 1) to typeof(string);
traces
|  summarize AggregatedValue = dcount(roleInstanceId) by bin_at(timestamp, 30m, (datetime(2021-04-05T23:27:46.0000000)  - 15m * (2 - toint(LSA_optimization_sliding_win))))
```

And how can I make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Just like the error message says, the 3rd argument must be a constant, which in your query it's a non-const calculation.

Comment: Thank you Slavik, is there any way to workaround it ?  We mvexpand our rows by column "LSA_optimization_sliding_win", and we need the bin_at to be shifted according to the corresponding number in that column.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, you can use `extend` to "normalize" the per-record value of timestamp, and then in `summarize` you can just use `bin` instead of `bin_at`.